# Trying to find existing data in array

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to create a program that check if there's any available information that is given in the array

```
<?php

$fnames = array("Patrick","Janjan","Nico");
$mnames = array("Dasal","Agustino","Macatangay");
$lnames = array("Paredes","Fung","Acedillo");

$names = array($fnames,$mnames,$lnames);

if(in_array("Patrick",$names)){
  echo "It exists";
}
else{
  echo "Doesn't exists";
}

?>
```

The output is always Doesnt exists

Comment: that's because you have three array's nested, you're not looking in the right place

Comment: Use `array_merge` instead just `array()`. That is perfect solution.

Comment: You can easily debug this with `print`. (hint: array of arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Try in single array, not in multi array

```
<?php

$fnames = array("Patrick","Janjan","Nico");
$mnames = array("Dasal","Agustino","Macatangay");
$lnames = array("Paredes","Fung","Acedillo");
$search = 'Patrick';
if(in_array($search,$fnames) || in_array($search,$mnames) || in_array($search,$lnames)){
  echo "It exists";
}
else{
  echo "Doesn't exists";
}

?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1013637)

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge` instead just `array`:

```
$fnames = array("Patrick","Janjan","Nico");
$mnames = array("Dasal","Agustino","Macatangay");
$lnames = array("Paredes","Fung","Acedillo");

$names = array_merge($fnames,$mnames,$lnames);  // Notice array_merge here.

if(in_array("Patrick",$names)){
  echo "It exists";
}
else{
  echo "Doesn't exists";
}
```

Comment: This is the compact and quicker code rather than using three different conditions in `IF`.

Comment: Yes its `compact` but not quicker, because its also doing `array_merge` and now you mashed up all names into one.

Answer (score 0):

You created a nested array, so you have to access it differently.
Imagine what happens when you write it down into one variable:

```
$names = array(
    array("Patrick","Janjan","Nico"),
    array("Dasal","Agustino","Macatangay"),
    array("Paredes","Fung","Acedillo")
);
```

As you can see, there are three arrays within your outer array. To solve your problem, you can make use of `array_merge()`, which creates **one** array from your three arrays:

```
$names = array_merge($fnames, $mnames, $lnames);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_intersect also.
Since we know "patrick" is going to be in a subarray of an array we can find it with [["Patrick"]].

```
$fnames = array("Patrick","Janjan","Nico");
$mnames = array("Dasal","Agustino","Macatangay");
$lnames = array("Paredes","Fung","Acedillo");

$names = array($fnames,$mnames,$lnames);

if(array_intersect($names, [["Patrick"]])){
  echo "It exists";
}
else{
  echo "Doesn't exists";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <?php
$fnames = array("Patrick","Janjan","Nico");
$mnames = array("Dasal","Agustino","Macatangay");
$lnames = array("Paredes","Fung","Acedillo");

$names = array($fnames,$mnames,$lnames);
if (in_array("Patrick",$names[0]))
 {
  echo "Match found";
   }
  else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>
```

This gives output Match found...